# What is the currently focused component?

Tags: android, android-layout, focus, components, widget

I have some activity and from that activity I start a new one. This (the second) activity is quite complex and the point is I want to know what component (which widget) is focused.

well my problem is that I have soft keyboard shown on some devices (and the same build of the app starts the activity B with hidden keyboard).

Is there any command or snipped that can find which of the component(widgets) has the focus at the moment ?

Edit:
getcurrent focus return null :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getCurrentFocus() on the Window of this Activity returned currently focused view. I called getCurrentFocus in wrong place :).